# Using ArcGIS Feature Compare in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcmap, if-statement

I am trying to write a script partially in ArcGIS ModelBuilder and adding an if statement on my own.

It uses the Feature Compare tool in arcgis and I want to use the result.getOutput in an If statement so that if it is true then run a process - in this case a copy features.

The big picture here is to compare two features and if there are differences in them then truncate and update.

**I need help with the If statement or alternative. I don't think I'm getting result.getOutput value to pass to the if statement and then run the if.  Can anyone see where this might be incorrect?**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------    -
# compare_test1.py
# Created on: 2015-11-03 14:06:44.00000
#   (generated by ArcGIS/ModelBuilder)
# Description: 
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Import arcpy module
import arcpy


# Local variables:
TONGIS_PARKING = "Database Connections\\ESRI10PUB GIS_VIEWER WAREHOUSE.sde\\TONGIS.PARKING"
TONGIS_PARKING__2_ = "Database Connections\\ESRI10PUB GIS_VIEWER WAREHOUSE.sde\\TONGIS.PARKING"
test = ""
PARKING_CopyFeatures = "G:\\Projects 10\\Corporate Services\\Information Technology\\Default.gdb\\PARKING_CopyFeatures"

# Process: Feature Compare
result = arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(TONGIS_PARKING, TONGIS_PARKING__2_, "GLOBALID", "ALL", "", "0.00001 Unknown", "0", "0", "", "", "NO_CONTINUE_COMPARE", test)
changes = result.getOutput(1)
#print "Comparision Result is: " + changes
change = str(changes)
if change == "True":
    # Process: Copy Features
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(TONGIS_PARKING__2_, PARKING_CopyFeatures, "", "0", "0", "0")
```

Comment: Is it a typo that your `if` statement is not using `change`?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it in my question.

Comment: check if `result.getOutput(1)` is actually `"True"` or `True` (there's a difference).

Comment: For boolean True/False you should not include the quotation marks as you elude to @Paul H

Comment: @JeffMay, personally, I wouldn't put it past arcpy to return a string, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case sensitivity issue. `getOutput(1)` on the `Result` object returned by Feature Compare will be `'true'` or `'false'` (not `'True'` or `'False'`, or `True` or `False`).

Note: `getOutput(n)` always returns a string (for any geoprocessing tool).